# transaction layout

Tags: transactions

I want to make a reference document that shows a full bitcoin transaction with brackets or lines to indicated each different part of the transaction. Then add a description of each part below the image and how you determine where each part begins (ie. address and checksum). I'm sure most (maybe all) of this has already been done but Im having trouble find them. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why raw Bitcoin transaction are in hex format?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95814/why-raw-bitcoin-transaction-are-in-hex-format) Answers there point to resources such as https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference which break down the raw transaction format

Comment: not really. I was thinking something more like a block explorer image but with something that breaks up the address for more details. those might be useful for the description but mostly i need the overview right now.

Comment: Take a look at https://learnmeabitcoin.com/ maybe

Comment: What tool are you using to make your reference document? Notepad?, Word? an HTML5/CSS3 editor? Wordpress, some PDF toolchain? Markdown? PHP? C# ?