# transaction parts and identification

Tags: transactions

I'm making a reference document for bitcoin transactions using this transaction (its a random transaction).

hash: [image]

it contains

[image]

I would like to add detail to each of the addresses but I'm not sure what all the parts are. What the components and how do I mark them like that bit at the beginning in red.

Comment: Isn't this a repeat of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/106798/13866 ?

Comment: yes but that was to see if I missed an all ready made document or similar and could simply use that rather than making my own. When I made this I had seen nothing that fit what I needed so Im making it, but I'm not confident that I'll do it right so I'm asking for some help on the specifics. To answer your question in the other page, word others need to see this and I don't trust them to be able to use anything else.  They are not very computer savvy.

Comment: So, are you really asking how to mark text in red in MS Word???? Surely not. It's hard to help as I find  the question a bit vague. Sorry.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I think Anonymous wants to know different parts of a Bitcoin address which can be highlighted in a block explorer. Example: Prefix, Checksum etc.

Comment: exactly what Prayank said.

Comment: https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/address this link will be helpful to understand P2PKH and P2SH addreses

Comment: so I have used learn me a bitcoin quite a bit, but I have a problem. I think that I need just that last 8 characters for both p2pkh and p2sh's checksum, however I can't check that as I need the hexidecimal notation for everything I can find I don't have a means of converting it back. I think I just don't know where to find the hexidecimal version of the address. Which I could then use to generate the checksum for confirmation. I would then label both the main address and check sum in blue and green respectively along with descriptions